# Apache docx not encoding properly through reverse proxy

Tags: apache, mime-types, reverse-proxy, apache-modules

My setup: I have two zones separated by a firewall. There is an application server/apache stack in zone 1, and separate apache reverse proxy server in zone 1 that allows communication between both zones. A user in zone 2 pulls information from the application in zone 1 via this reverse proxy server.

Basic 'flow' of files:

File residing on zone 1 app server -> zone 1 reverse proxy -> zone 2 user -> downloaded file

The problem I'm encountering is that when a docx or xlsx (doc and xls work fine) type of file is uploaded to the application server in zone 1, it doesn't open when downloaded from the user in zone 2. I can position myself in zone 1, upload a file directly to the application server and download it again without a problem.

I have docx/xlsx/etc in the mime.types file for Apache on both servers. The proxy is running mime magic as well but there are no docx/xlsx/etc entries in mime magic.

Does the mime magic module override mime.types? Any other thoughts?